# C++ Function Overload / With objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I made a class Valjak (Roller), and gave it variables `h` (height) and `r` (radius) and made functions for area (`Oplosje`) and volume (`Volumen`).

I created 2 objects and now I need to overload operator `+`  in such way that result of adding two objects from class Valjak (roller) creates a new third object that has as height equal to the height of first object plus the height of second object, and radius that is the radius of first object plus radius of third object.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Valjak{
private: float r, h;
public: 
    Valjak(){
        r = 1;
        h = 1;
    }
    Valjak(float rr, float hh){
        r = rr;
        h = hh;
    }
    void Oplosje(){
        cout << "Oplosje valjka je: " << 2 * (pow(r, 2)*3.14) + 2 * r*h << endl;
    }
    void Volumen(){
        cout << "Volumen je: " << (pow(r, 2)*3.14) * h << endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    Valjak V1;
    Valjak V2(5, 10);
    cout << "Vrijednosti prvog objekta!" << endl;
    V1.Oplosje();
    V1.Volumen();
    cout << "Vrijednosti drugog objekta" << endl;
    V2.Oplosje();
    V2.Volumen();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? I don't see any attempt in overloading `operator+`. You should use initializer lists to initialize member fields in costructors though.

Comment: hmm i didnt try anything , because i am unfamilliar with it and dont see point of using it now as a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must write getters for `r` and `h`, let's name them `get_r` and `get_h`:

```
class Valjak {
// ...
public:
    float get_r() { return r; }
    float get_h() { return h; }
// ...
}
```

Then overload operator `+` for two objects of `Valjak` class:

```
Valjak operator+(const Valjak & a, const Valjak & b)
{
    return Valjak(a.get_r() + b.get_r(), a.get_h() + b.get_h());
}
```